# Website spits out PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR in firefox's incognito

Tags: firefox, ssl, ssl-certificate, private-browsing, letsencrypt

So I have a site that uses letsencrypt and ssl works fine when I'm browsing my site in firefox. The moment I try browsing my site using incognito mode in firefox my browser throws this secure connection failed error and spits out PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR.

I can't seem to come to a solution and it only happens in firefox. Chrome & Edge works in both normal & incognito windows.

How exactly do I fix a PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and the solution was for me to enable the `ssl_session_cache`

I'm using nginx so I had to add the following line in my config:

```
   ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
```

Comment: Oh man you just saved me and many others so much time. Thank you. This is the only answer online for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Tokk for the answer. For Ubuntu 20.04, I modified `/etc/apache2/mods-available/ssl.conf` as follows:

```
       # SSLSessionCache         shmcb:${APACHE_RUN_DIR}/ssl_scache(512000)
        SSLSessionCache         shmcb:${APACHE_RUN_DIR}/ssl_scache(10000000)
```

Then typing `sudo service apache2 restart` solved the issue!