# Secure Connection Failed Using Firefox with PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR

Tags: firefox

Recently I received a very weird error that got me worried. I was feeling an application on a website that is against duplicate entry. After feeling part 1 on the form, I click "Next" and completed part 2. Upon clicking the **submit** button on part 2, I get the error below:

```
Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to <website name> PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR


    The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
    Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
```

I tried to refresh firefox but got thesame error. So I then open thesame website with a VPN enabled Opera and submitted my application successfully. What worries me is whether the first submission done on firefox was received by their system? and what is the cause of such error?

NB: i am using my 4G mobile phone data to browse.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is NSS error -5961 (PR\_CONNECT\_RESET\_ERROR)](https://superuser.com/questions/916077/what-is-nss-error-5961-pr-connect-reset-error)

Comment: The error indicates the data was never submitted.  It likely has something to do with your 4G connection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1484466/website-spits-out-pr-connect-reset-error-in-firefoxs-incognito

Answer (score 0):

This means your connection is being actively monitored and a firewall is intentionally set up to block those kinds of connections as it cannot intercept them.

As all HTTPS sites leaks their intended hostname (SNI), that appliance won't allow your connection because it cannot record your HTTPS traffic (not true in corporate environments).

In other words: You're certainly accessing some website form a enterprise computer or you're being blocked because your ISP has been served with a request to block some websites (most likely filesharing, pornography or music/video websites).

Comment: The OP is using a mobile phone connection so your comments on enterprise machines isn't relevant. Good shout on the ISP intercepting illegal or banned sites though.